# JavaScript :Generate objects by using for loop

Tags: javascript

So for example I have 3 arrays in total and it's like below

```
var arr1 = ['123','456','789'];
var arr2 = ['435','551','778'];
var arr3 = ['5','7','1'];
```

and i tried to store them in a object for further usage.

```
       var Chart = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length ;i++){

             Chart = {
                    x : arr1[i],
                    y : arr2[i],
                    z : arr3[i]
                };

        }
```

My method has done the job but when i console it and use it it only returns the very last set of data.

So only  `{arr1[2],arr2[2],arr3[2]}` been used the rest are missing.

how may i solve this?

Answer (score 5):

You are re-assigning value of variable in each iteration, instead initialize it as an array and push value to it.

```js
var arr1 = ['123','456','789'];
var arr2 = ['435','551','778'];
var arr3 = ['5','7','1'];
var Chart = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  Chart.push({
    x: arr1[i],
    y: arr2[i],
    z: arr3[i]
  });
}

console.log(Chart);
```

Comment: @anson920520 : on each iteration you where re assigning with the new object created

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 by object destructuring;

```js
var arr1 = ['123','456','789'],
    arr2 = ['435','551','778'],
    arr3 = ['5','7','1'],
   Chart = {"x":[],"y":[],"z":[]};
Chart = {arr1,arr2,arr3};
console.log(Chart);
```

Answer (score 0):

An object cannot be initialized as you are doing in your following code.

```
var Chart = "";
```

It should be like following

```
var Chart = [];
```

Then the assignments to the object properties would be like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  Chart.push({
x: arr1[i],
y: arr2[i],
z: arr3[i]
  });
```

Final Snippet will be

```
var Chart = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  Chart.push({
    x: arr1[i],
    y: arr2[i],
    z: arr3[i]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6:

```
var arr1 = ['123','456','789'];
var arr2 = ['435','551','778'];
var arr3 = ['5','7','1'];

arr1.map((x, i) => ({x, y: arr2[i], z: arr3[i]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the previous answers you re-assign the values, and notice how to initialize an object in code below, try this:

```
var arr1 = ['123','456','789'];
var arr2 = ['435','551','778'];
var arr3 = ['5','7','1'];

var Chart = {};
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length ;i++){
    Chart['y'+i] = arr1[i];
    Chart['x'+i] = arr2[i];
    Chart['x'+i] = arr3[i];
}
```